# Basic angle geometry question

Tags: geometry

[image]

I've faced a question that needed to find angle $\gamma$ as a part of it and the solution came from $\gamma= \beta - \alpha$. How did the book arrive to such conclusion, and does this apply for every similar case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angle "next to" $\beta$ (supplementary to $\beta$) is $180^\circ-\beta$.  The sum of the angles of a triangle is $180^\circ$, so
$$\alpha+(180^\circ-\beta)+\gamma=180^\circ.$$

**Remark:** This is an often-used result. Usually it is stated as follows. The *external* angle ($\beta$) at a vertex is the sum of the *internal* angles at the other two vertices. So $\alpha+\gamma=\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

total degrees in a triangle = 180

$$\beta_{supplement} = 180-\beta$$

so

$$180 = \gamma + \alpha + \beta_{supplement}$$